# Java 2D Game NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am trying to create a 2D game in Java where a user is prompted for a row width and column length. A 'world' object is created that looks like this when printed (where P is the player's character):

```
P---
----
----
----
```

The user can then enter up, down, left, right or exit which should move the P around and do nothing if the move would move the character off the map. My issue is after I enter the width and length, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at World.displayWorld(Driver.java:90)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:28)
```

I believe this means that Java is seeing worldDimensions.length as empty/null?? I thought I was assigning a value to it when the world object is created.. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //Create a scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

        boolean exit = true;

        //Prompt user to enter world width and height
        System.out.print("World width: ");
        int userWidth = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("World height: ");
        int userHeight = input.nextInt();

        //Create a world object
        World world1 = new World(userWidth, userHeight);
        world1.displayWorld();

        System.out.println("Possible inputs: up, down, left, right, exit");

        while (exit = true) {
            //display world
            world1.displayWorld();

            System.out.print("ACTION > ");
            String userAction = input.next();

            if (userAction == "up" || userAction == "down" || userAction == "left" || userAction == "right" || userAction == "exit") {
                switch (userAction) {
                    case "up":
                        world1.moveUp();
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        world1.moveDown();
                        break;
                    case "left":
                        world1.moveLeft();
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        world1.moveRight();
                        break;
                    case "exit":
                        exit = false;
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input. Possible inputs are: up, down, left, right, or exit.");
            }
        }

    }
}

class World {
    static private char[][] worldDimensions;
    static private int characterRow;
    static private int characterColumn;

    public World(int userWidth, int userHeight) {
        char[][] worldDimensions = new char[userHeight][userWidth];
        int characterRow = 0;
        int characterColumn = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < worldDimensions.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < worldDimensions[row].length; column++) {
                if (characterRow == row && characterColumn == column) {
                    worldDimensions[row][column] = (char)
                    'P';
                } else {
                    worldDimensions[row][column] = (char)
                    '-';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayWorld() {
        for (int row = 0; row < worldDimensions.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < worldDimensions[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(worldDimensions[row][column]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        if (characterRow - 1 >= 0) {
            characterRow--;
        }
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        if (characterRow + 1 <= worldDimensions[0].length) {
            characterRow++;
        }
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        if (characterColumn - 1 >= 0) {
            characterColumn--;
        }
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        if (characterRow + 1 <= worldDimensions.length) {
            characterRow++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`equals() to compare strings`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Also check [`What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: For future reference, its useful to indicate which line the null pointer is on - as opposed to us having to find it.

Comment: There are at least three mistakes here - using `=` instead of *just* `exit`, using `==` to compare Strings, and the redundant cast to `char`...

Comment: Change "char[][] worldDimensions = ..." for just "worldDimensions = ..." at the first line of World class.

Comment: You could get rid of the if-else statement surrounding the switch statement and just add a `default` case.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone! It helped me a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You're shadowing `worldDimensions` inside of your constructor.  The local declaration does not give you the same field as previously declared.

Simply remove the declaration and you'll be alright (at least for that error):

```
worldDimensions = new char[userHeight][userWidth];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your class variable worldDimensions. Your World constructor should look like the following

```
public World(int userWidth, int userHeight)
{
//here is where you were overwriting the global variable, leaving it null
//and populating the local one instead
worldDimensions = new char[userHeight][userWidth];
int characterRow = 0;
int characterColumn = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < worldDimensions.length; row++)
    {
    for (int column = 0; column < worldDimensions[row].length; column++)
        {
        if (characterRow == row && characterColumn == column)
            {
            worldDimensions[row][column] = (char)'P';
            }
        else
            {
            worldDimensions[row][column] = (char)'-';
            }
        }
    }
}
```